# How to show Project folders in browser

Tags: asp.net

I m working in asp.net. I have created folders in my project folder and I want this to show on browser so that when users click on folder name it lists down all the files residing inside that folder.

[image]

Below i am attaching a picture which is a perfect example of what I want to do.

[image]

I have never done anything like this so i want guidance for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, if you enable Directory Browsing in IIS, a user can view like this -

[image]

***However, it is not what you want in ASP.Net Application.*** Instead, you need to create a page with GridView or other data bound control, and bind it with Data.

If you want too fancy, you want to go with Commercial Components like [Telerik FileExplorer](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx).